# Draw route and avoid obstacles

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

I have several coordonates (Latitude,Longitude) I want to draw a route but without passing trough buildings how can I do that?

Comment: I won't downvote now since it's already been done, but how about: No evidence of research effort; no specific query re programming; request for how-to when SO is not a tutorial site, for starters? The Google Maps API will do directions with waypoints, but a general tutorial would be out of place.

Comment: @AndrewLeach a starting point would be useful I know how to draw a route on google maps using JSON but i want it to stop passing trough buildings...so any help would be useful I don't need a tutorial

Comment: Posting code that does the job doesn't seem right to me

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints Directions don't pass through buildings, they follow roads; and you can pass through known coordinates by specifying them as waypoints.

Comment: @AndrewLeach you can post your comment as an answer so I could accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints

Directions don't pass through buildings, they follow roads; and you can pass through known coordinates by specifying them as waypoints.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of any routing service that sends you through buildings - they all follow the public road network. Here's the SDK for the Bing Maps Routing API:

http://bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#RESTServices2

To route between two lat/lngs, just set the values of the waypoints using the numbered wp.x variables in the URL request. e.g to route between (52,-0.5) and (51,0) as follows:

http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes?wp.0=52;-0.5&wp.1=51;0&routePathOutput=Points&output=json&jsonp=RouteCallback